# How to Associate WinUI3 app name deployment

Tags: xamarin, maui, maui-windows

I have a Maui WinUI3 app. But when I try to associate the package to the app in Microsoft Store from Visual Studio 2022 it doesn’t list the app . The app is in another organization but my Ms user was granted access .

Comment: Could you please tell me if you've already been assigned a role by the account owner of that organization? Like mentioned here: [Assign roles to account users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/partner-center/assign-roles-to-account-users)

Comment: Developer role assigned

Comment: Can you see the app in the partner center dashboard? Does the app have a package before? If it is, please make sure you've enabled the option for `showing apps already have packages` in the association window.